# Desktop Google chrome browser disable zoom in?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromium

I have tried all method out there for to disable the zoom in (on touch screen) while having Google chrome as kiosk.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi' name='viewport' />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

None of above is working. Is there any single way to disable this bad boy's?

Comment: Have you tried `<meta content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,width=device-width" name="viewport">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to disable pinch-zoom declaratively - desktop browsers ignore the viewport `<meta>` tag.

If you control the page content, you can use [touch-action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) or listen to touch events and call preventDefault() when two fingers are down.

If you don't control content but do control the kiosk setup, you can start Chrome with the `--disable-pinch` command line flag.

Comment: I control the kiosk (i am the God). Does latest google chrome support that `--disable-pinch` that would be great or is it only supported less then version 50?

Comment: It should be supported on the current version, are you having trouble getting it to work?